How do I display the result using a Submit Button?
I want this form function in HTML to display the result after the Submit button is clicked. At this time, it executes the result when I enter numbers in those three input boxes (width, height, length), but I want to add a submit button, and when someone clicks on it, the result should be shown in a box.


<form oninput="x.value=parseFloat(((a.value)*parseFloat(b.value)*parseFloat(c.value))*1.3).toFixed(2)">
  <label for="a">Width (ft)</label>&nbsp
  <input type="number" id="a" value=""><br><br>
  <label for="b">Length (ft)</label>
  <input type="number" id="b" value=""><br><br>
  <label for="c">Height (ft)</label>
  <input type="number" id="c" value=""><br><br>
  <button>Submit</button>
  <output name="x" for="a b c"></output>
</form>




add an event listener

I made a snippet. I removed the  and a loose </p>

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', (event) => { event.preventDefault(); x.textContent = (a.value * b.value * c.value * 1.3).toFixed(2);});

Sounds like you should take some tutorials on sending forms through JavaScript

@HereticMonkey They do not want to send the form, just use it as a placeholder for fields and to have an event handler

@mplungjan Stop taking titles so literally.

@HereticMonkey Why would I stop that? Programming is literally built on taking things literally. OP needs to read about event handlers more than form submissions to servers

Introduction to events

Remove the oninput property from the form. To prevent the form from automatically submitting, add a button element with type="button". Create a JavaScript function to carry out the computation and display the result.
Corrected Code:


<form id="calcForm">
    <label for="a">Width (ft)</label>
    <input type="number" id="a"><br><br>
    <label for="b">Length (ft)</label>
    <input type="number" id="b"><br><br>
    <label for="c">Height (ft)</label>
    <input type="number" id="c"><br><br>
    <button type="button" onclick="calculateResult()">Submit</button>
</form>
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
    function calculateResult() {
        var width = parseFloat(document.getElementById('a').value) || 0;
        var length = parseFloat(document.getElementById('b').value) || 0;
        var height = parseFloat(document.getElementById('c').value) || 0;
        var result = (width * length * height * 1.3).toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById('result').innerText = 'Total: ' + result;
    }
</script>




This answered my question. Straightforward.

I strongly recommend to use an external eventListener on the submit event as suggested in the comments

Your code <form oninput="***"> handles the change event, but you should handle the submit event instead to write the output on button click. I also added a name attribute for each of the fields, which helps in generating the object from the form data. I also used square bracket [] notation to read 'length' property because length is a keyword.


<form>
      <label for="a">Width (ft)</label>&nbsp
      <input type="number" name="width" id="a" value="" />
      <label for="b">Length (ft)</label>
      <input type="number" name="length" id="b" value="" />
      <label for="c">Height (ft)</label>
      <input type="number" name="height" id="c" value="" />
      <output name="x" for="a b c"></output>
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
    <script>
      const form = document.querySelector('form');
      const output = document.querySelector('output');
      
      form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const formData = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(form));
        const result = +formData.width * +formData['length'] * +formData.height;
        output.innerHTML = result;
      });
    </script>




Interesting method, but instead of name you could change the IDs to be more descriptive and just use them. Also you miss the 1.3

FormData objects create key-value pairs based on the name attribute, which is why I added the name attribute. However, I would be happy to learn about any solutions that can create key-value pairs using IDs.

That is not what I meant. You can drop the form data and just have
const result = a.value * b.value * c.value * 1.3 without any other code to get the values or the fields

Thank you for pointing that out! I wasn't aware that you could directly access the elements with id's directly like that without explicitly querying them first.

First remove the oninput attribute from the form and add a submit button for calculating when the user clicks. On that submit button you can use the onclick method for calling javascript function. Inside that function, you can do your required calculations. Lastly, to show the result use the output element.
Follow these steps:
 <form id="calculationForm">
  <label for="a">Width (ft)</label>&nbsp
  <input type="number" id="a" value=""><br><be>
  <label for="b">Length (ft)</label>
  <input type="number" id="b" value=""><br><be>
  <label for="c">Height (ft)</label>
  <input type="number" id="c" value=""><br><be>
  <button type="button" onclick="calculate()">Submit</button><br><be>
  <label for="total">Result:</label>
  <output id="result"></output>
 </form>
<script>
    function calculate() {
    var width = parseFloat(document.getElementById('a').value) || 0;
    var length = parseFloat(document.getElementById('b').value) || 0;
    var height = parseFloat(document.getElementById('c').value) || 0;

    var total = (width * length * height) * 1.3;
    document.getElementById('result').value = total.toFixed(2);
    }
 </script>


You should prefer the form's submit event, it maximizes compatibility. A form won't always be submitted by a click on the submit button.


Change oninput to onsubmit
Change <button> to <button type="submit">
Add return false to cancel submit
Change x.value to x.innerText (and put id="x" instead of name="x")



<form onsubmit="x.innerText=parseFloat(((a.value)*parseFloat(b.value)*parseFloat(c.value))*1.3).toFixed(2); return false;">
  <label for="a">Width (ft)</label>&nbsp
  <input type="number" id="a" value=""><br><br>
  <label for="b">Length (ft)</label>
  <input type="number" id="b" value=""><br><br>
  <label for="c">Height (ft)</label>
  <input type="number" id="c" value=""><br><br>
  <label for="total"> <button type="submit"> Submit</button></label>
  <output id="x" for="a b c"> </output>
</form>




Buttons have type=submit by default.

Why is the button wrapped in a label element? "Submit" isn't a label to anything.

@Sean Because the original one was.

Although this works, you should always prefer adding eventlisteners in separate javascript.

Since this isn't submitting anything to a server, type="button" is more appropriate.

You are likely looking for onsubmit, which will be triggered by the <button>...</button> in your form. Be careful though, submitting a form triggers a page refresh. You can cancel this by adding a <form onsubmit="...; return false" >...</form> at the end of your handler.
However, putting your handler in the html isn't a best practice. I would recommend to add a script tag and put your javascript in there:
<form id="form">
    <label for="a">Width (ft)</label>&nbsp
    <input type="number" id="a" value=""><br><br>
    <label for="b">Length (ft)</label>
    <input type="number" id="b" value=""><br><br>
    <label for="c">Height (ft)</label>
    <input type="number" id="c" value=""><br><br>
    <button type="submit"> Submit</button>
</form>

<output id="output" for="a b c"> </output>

<script>
    const form = document.getElementById('form');
    const output = document.getElementById('output');

    form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
        // Prevent the page reload
        e.preventDefault();

        output.innerText = parseFloat(this.a.value) * parseFloat(this.b.value) * parseFloat(this.c.value) * 1.3;
    });
</script>


Your form should handle the submission so that you can press the Enter key at any time to submit.
Your input fields, at a minimum should be:
<label for="field-x">X (ft)</label>
<input type="number" id="field-X" name="X" required step="0.01" value="1">

Where x is the variable in the volume calculation. These fields should be required, with a minimum step of at least 0.01 (the hundredths place). This way you can enter floating-point numbers into the field.
To grab the field, access it on the form via:
const x = form.elements.x.valueAsNumber; // Can't name field "length"

Accessing the valueAsNumber property is more idiomatic than:
const x = parseInt(form.elements.x.value.trim() ?? '0', 10);

Here is a full demo utilizing native HTML form submission and validation.


const scalingFactor = 1.3;

function calculateVolume(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Prevent page navigation
  const form = event.target;

  // Get the input values from the form
  const width = form.elements.width.valueAsNumber;
  const length = form.elements.len.valueAsNumber; // Can't name field "length"
  const height = form.elements.height.valueAsNumber;
    
  // Calculate volume and apply scaling factor
  const volume = width * length * height;
  const scaledValue = volume * scalingFactor;

  // Update the result
  const resultEl = document.querySelector('#result > .result');
  resultEl.textContent = scaledValue.toFixed(2);
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

hr { width: 100%; }

.grid-form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
  grid-row-gap: 0.5rem;
  grid-column-gap: 1rem;
  justify-content: center;
}
.grid-form button[type="submit"] {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
<form class="grid-form" name="volume-form" onSubmit="calculateVolume(event)">
  <label for="field-width">Width (ft)</label>
  <input type="number" id="field-width" name="width" required step="0.01" value="1">
  <label for="field-length">Length (ft)</label>
  <input type="number" id="field-length" name="len" required step="0.01" value="1">
  <label for="field-height">Height (ft)</label>
  <input type="number" id="field-height" name="height" required step="0.01" value="1">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<hr>
<div id="result">
  <strong>Calculated Volume:</strong>
  <span class="result">0.00</span>
</div>



PS, you should make your scaling factor a form field as well.

.elements are not needed. form.len.value should work too
